# Send values to jquery function

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I try send values to jquery function , inside function i have some class and i need send some vars in each case

```
function videos_pop(idv)
{
jQuery('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
disableOn: 700,
type:'iframe',
mainClass:'mfp-fade',
removalDelay:160,
preloader:false,
fixedContentPos:false
});
}
```

In this case the value for pass inside function it´s **(idv)** and i need add this to the end of each class as in this way :

> jQuery('.popup-youtube**+idv**, .popup-vimeo**+idv**, .popup-gmaps**+idv**').magnificPopup({

The problem i think writte bad the sintax for this and don´t take the value send across the function , because i supose i must writte in special for because the classes inside **('')** and separated by **,**

Only it´s this the problem , thank´s for help me in this , regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to concatenate the strings for the selector.

```
function videos_pop(idv)
{
    var selector = '.popup-youtube' + idv + ', .popup-vimeo' + idv + ', .popup-gmaps' + idv;
    jQuery(selector).magnificPopup({
        disableOn: 700,
        type:'iframe',
        mainClass:'mfp-fade',
        removalDelay:160,
        preloader:false,
        fixedContentPos:false
    });
}
```

You can also put a placeholder in that selector and then use  combination of `.split()` and `.join()`.

```
function videos_pop(idv)
{
    var selector = '.popup-youtube[idv], .popup-vimeo[idv], .popup-gmaps[idv]'
        .split('[idv]')
        .join(idv);
    jQuery(selector).magnificPopup({
        disableOn: 700,
        type:'iframe',
        mainClass:'mfp-fade',
        removalDelay:160,
        preloader:false,
        fixedContentPos:false
    });
}
```

... or create a regular expression and use `.replace()` (just remember the global `g` flag).

```
function videos_pop(idv)
{
    var selector = '.popup-youtube[idv], .popup-vimeo[idv], .popup-gmaps[idv]'
        .replace(/\[idv\]/g, idv);
    jQuery(selector).magnificPopup({
        disableOn: 700,
        type:'iframe',
        mainClass:'mfp-fade',
        removalDelay:160,
        preloader:false,
        fixedContentPos:false
    });
}
```